# Using Wordpress Event Registration forms on Multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Thought this would help someone else.

I have one CiviCRM on a multi site installation and was obtaining "You do not have permission to access this page" when displaying a form on a second multi site.

This appears the second site doesn't have the anonymous role setup per:
https://civicrm.org/blogs/haystack/working-civicrm-46-wordpress

I will post the next post as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Place this in your functions.php file

register_activation_hook( **FILE**, 'civicrm_activate');

// Assign minimum capabilities for all wordpress roles and create anonymous_user' role
civicrm_wp_set_capabilities();

This only needs to run once per site to create the role.

Answer (score 1):

If you receive domain redirects, try something like this in your CiviCRM configuration:

if (!defined('CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' );
}

I would probably only allow the domain in an array for security.