# Anonymous user permissions column missing

Tags: wordpress, permissions, anonymous-user

Our users trigger a “you don’t have permission to access this page” error when trying to make a contribution or opt out of an email. I’ve read some responses on SE about setting permissions for an anonymous user which seem related. But when I visit the “WordPress access control page” there is no column for Anonymous user permissions. What would cause that and how do I fix it?

Comment: That's odd... Just checking: if you go to `Administer > Users & Permissions > Permissions (Access Control)`, then `WordPress Access Control` - what columns do you see?  Maybe add a screenshot to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I may have found the answer [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28907/no-anonymous-user-role-in-civicrm-administer-civicrm-access-control-wordpres?rq=1). I created an anonymous_user role as described, and the column appears in the permissions page now. I am testing to see if the errors go away.

Edit: it does work. BTW this is not a multi site install as was described on the linked issue, but it worked here on our single site.